# ionic or Angular 0r Web-component datagrid

Tags: angular, polymer, web-component, ionic3

I need to bid on a project to replace a Silverlight app with an HTML5 equivalent. This app has hundreds of pages, many of which use the Silverlight datagrid. This datagrid has many nice features that need to be in the replacement:

resizable columns
sortable (by clicking on column headers)
re-order columns (by dragging them)
making columns visible/invisible
pagination
context menus

Does anyone know of any open source component I could use to get some or all of this functionality?

Thanks

Comment: Big webapplication? Try look into Angular. Ionic is pure for mobile apps, also Angular code work in Ionic cause of TypeScript. Web-component datagrid look more like a screen by screen application (not really know it)

Comment: You're **WRONG**. You can use Ionic for developing any platform. Mobile - Web - desktop. And PWAs too.See this: http://blog.ionic.io/what-progressive-web-apps-can-do-for-you/ @Swoox

Comment: @Sampath I strongly advice to use angular as webApp and Ionic for Mobile App. But yeah it's possible to build. But I wouldn't recommend it.
And the link you posted is very new. So it's still up in development.

Comment: Can you tell us the reasons? Do you know about the `Ionic 4` and `Stencil` project? Please see that too: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil @Swoox

Comment: Let me check first.

Comment: @Sampath I think Angular is more fit cause the freedom you have with it. Ionic is basicly a framework build on Angular, going it's own way now. Next to that Angular use AOT and Universal to render websites quicker. I don't know about Ionic performance on large scale projects.

Comment: `Ionic 3` also use `AOT` out of the box. `Ionic 4` will have `Server Side Rendering (SSR)` out of the box.Hope you'll read above doc @Swoox

Comment: @Sampath I will do thanks.

Comment: You're warmly welcome :) @Swoox

Comment: @Sampath actually I checked out Ionic before ( few months ago) had trouble building web App on **--prod** cause no files where minified do you have an **article** on that?

Comment: Yep, see this: https://javebratt.com/pwa-faq/ @Swoox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you can use [**Angular 2 Grid**](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-getting-started/#gsc.tab=0).It has very rich features.

[image]

Comment: Just what the Doctor ordered!

Comment: Excellent ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it is answered but it is fair to mention `ExtJS` with its `grid` and `pivotgrid`.

[Samples](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/examples/kitchensink/#pivot-grids)